# AC to DC LED driver - help to determine fault or suitable replacement

Tags: led-driver, lighting

Our home's exterior landscape lighting is powered by a transformer that outputs 12V AC. I have two (expensive) LED landscape lights and one of them isn't lighting up anymore. I opened it up and found inside an LED driver that looks like it converts the landscape 12VAC input to the sufficient DC power needed by the LEDs. According to the official specs of the LED light, the total power draw is 9W. The LEDs themselves are arranged in three arrays of 9 LEDs, for a total of 27 LEDs. I have another working light (same model) outside and measured the <strike>current</strike> voltage with a multimeter when the LEDs are lit, and it outputs 26V DC.

I measured the output of the LED driver in the lamp that doesn't light up and it seems to output only around 18-24 VDC, so probably not enough to light the 3 x 9 array of LEDs. I also tested the LEDS from the non-working light in the working light, and the LEDs (from the bad light) work great when connected to the working LED driver.

Below is a picture of the driver board. I suspect the IC chip in the middle (XL6005E1) is possibly faulty, but who knows? Is there is a good way to determine which component(s) are to blame for the low voltage output, or would it be best to build/buy a suitable replacement? Would a replacement LED driver need to output around 300mA output since I have 27 LEDs for a total of 9W (per official spec)?

In regards to replacements, I've looked into LED "boost" modules that would accept the correct input voltage of 10~12VAC, but everything I'm finding it DC-to-DC only in the correct input and output voltage range. I'm guessing that wouldn't work without some rectifiers? Looks like this board is using 2 pairs of rectifiers in a "full-wave" bridge rectifier setup to take advantage of the AC input and get smoother constant input power.

Any ideas/thoughts on how to best proceed?

(EDIT: the gray gunk is a non-conductive rubber/epoxy waterproof material)

[image: LED PCB-AC to DC boost]

Comment: `measured the current` ... you measured the voltage, not the current

Comment: [XL6005E1 Datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810151812_XLSEMI-XL6005E1_C73345.pdf).  Currently a few on [ebay](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p4432023.m570.l1313&_nkw=XL6005E1&_sacat=0) but auction sites are notorious for selling poor-quality or even counterfeit chips.  Also measure those resistors to see if they match their markings.

Comment: Good points. I'm also not 100% sure it is the chip that is faulty, but this is only 1.5 years old and was sealed, so that is my best guess. If I end up trying to swap the chip, I also might attach a small heatsink to it to see if that lengthens its lifespan.

Answer (score 0):

The board you show is a DC design with a diode rectifier bridge added in front of it. The four black rectangles on the left are diodes, arranged in a full rectifier bridge.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCDVFG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Buy a DC constant current LED driver board, and feed it from AC using a diode bridge to rectify the input.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I appreciate it! I'll look into doing something like that.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is rectified input voltage at C1, if VAC is 12 V, with no load you should measure 14 V or a little more. If you measure 18..24 VDC at the output (higher than input), it looks like the boost function is somehow working. Check output capacitor, maybe it is faulty.
D6 and D7 looks like zener to over voltage protection, if any of these is shorten, it could also explain low output voltage. See schematics similar to your unit. Resistors for current feedback are marked with 1R80 (x2) and 2R00, the parallel should measure 0.62 Ohm, according to datasheet it is configured for 350 mA.
[image]

In case the XL600 is faulty, a similar driver (Boost, 3..36 V, 200 mV feedback voltage, 4 A peak current, overvoltage protection) could be  MPQ3362. Frecuency should be ajusted to minimum, 200 kHz. I think it make no sense to adapt, it is much effort, and as previous answer suggest, a DC driver is a good solution, maybe you can reuse the input rectifier and filter of the faulty one.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response and good ideas! I am kicking myself for not measuring the voltage at the two big capacitors and along the way. That MPQ3362 chip looks like a great alternative. According to the datasheet, it looks like I can use a 200KOhm resistor to set the frequency to 200kHz, and you are right as this would take some time/work, so maybe I'd put everything on a new replacement PCB at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go wrong there. Aside from the chip, you can check the diodes with a multimeter on diode range (most should read okay in-circuit).

The XL6005 is way overrated for the 350mA nominal output, (still could be killed by a voltage surge, such as from lightning) but maybe those two small diodes could be at fault. They look like they might  have used a couple 1A 1N5819-type SMT diodes in series rather than a 40V Schottky diode or a UF4005 etc. If they turn out to be the problem, you could consider something more robust.

Comment: Thanks, great ideas! I'll check those diodes to see if that leads me anywhere.